# How to refactor this array comparison with underscore.js?

Tags: functional-programming, coffeescript, refactoring, underscore.js

Can this code be refactored in a more functional/underscore style, mainly the part that checks for the presence of `addedEvents` in `actualEvents`?

```
describe 'when removing', ->

  it 'should remove all bound events from the window', ->
    @view.remove()
    addedEvents = ['dragenter', 'drop', 'dragleave', 'register']
    actualEvents = _.keys $._data(window, 'events') #=> ['onload', 'drop', 'etc.']
    for event in addedEvents
      present = _.contains(actualEvents, event)
      expect(present).toBe(false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using Coffee's postfix `for` and `in` operator can make the code more readable:

```
addedEvents = ['dragenter', 'drop', 'dragleave', 'register']
actualEvents = _.keys $._data(window, 'events') #=> ['onload', 'drop', 'etc.']
expect(event not in actualEvents).toBe(true) for event in addedEvents
```

If you're using Jasmine as your testing library, you can use the `toContain` which i think is more readable :)

```
expect(actualEvents).not.toContain(event) for event in addedEvents
```

Finally, if you want to go for a more functional style with Underscore, you can think of this assertion as checking that none of the `addedEvents` is present on the `actualEvents`, in other words, that the [intersection](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection) of those two arrays is empty:

```
expect(_.intersection(actualEvents, addedEvents).length).toBe(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want it to be using underscore functions, then the following should do.

```
addedEvents = ['dragenter', 'drop', 'dragleave', 'register']
actualEvents = _.keys $._data(window, 'events')
present = _.reduce addedEvents, ((prev, current) ->
  prev or _.contains actualEvents, current 
  ), false)
expect(present).toBe false
```

Of course, you can do this without underscore, but it requires ES5 functions:

```
addedEvents = ['dragenter', 'drop', 'dragleave', 'register']
actualEvents = Object.keys $._data(window, 'events')
present = addedEvents.reduce, ((prev, current) ->
  prev or actualEvents.indexOf(current) > -1
  ), false)
expect(present).toBe false
```